# App Store Review Guidelines: How to correctly handle/offer external purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I know, that this question is not directly related to any coding but there are several other question on SO about the App Store and its Guidelines. So I assume, this question is OK.

There are other questions about (more or less) the same issue. However they where asked / answered several years ago and the Guidelines have been updated since then. Additionally the circumstances are always a little bit different.

I am well aware, that nobody can give me any kind of guarantee on which interpretation of the Guidelines is correct. Not even Apple could do this, since everything depends on the review staff an its current mood. However It would help a lot get to know your opinion on what is allowed and what is not. Maybe you already encountered the same problem and have some useful recommendations.

**The set of facts:**

- A Shopping List app is offered in iOS App Store. The app offers functions to create and manage any kind of shopping list. These functions do NOT depend on any external purchase. The fee version limits the number of lists. This limit can be unlocked using an In App Purchase.
- There is also a WebApp version that offers the same functions (and a little more) as the iOS version. The WebApp has a one month free trial and can then be extended using a subscription model. **Subscriptions can only be ordered within the WepApp, not from within the iOS app.**
- Both version can be used completely independent from each other.
- Additionally the apps can be connected (REST API) to sync lists between them.
- Obviously there are pages/controls within the iOS App, that allows to setup the connection (enter username, password, etc.).
- Obviously the WebApp has to be described in some way to the user within the iOS App.
- Once the free trial ended or a subscription has expired, the sync will no longer work. In this case the user needs some kind of hint why sync is no longer available ==> There has to be information about the subscription model of the WebApp and a discription on how to renew the subscription.

**The "Problem":**

- The current App Store Guidelines are pretty vague on wether this kind of business model is allowed or not:

> **3.1.1 In-App Purchase:** If you want to unlock features or **functionality within your app**, (by way of example: subscriptions,
>   in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or
>   unlocking a full version), **you must use in-app purchase**. Apps may not
>   include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct
>   customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.

This paragraph is not as clear as it my appear on first sight. Unlocking  **functionality within your app** is only allowed by using IAP. Fine, so unlocking a app feature (e.g. creation of more than 2 shopping lists) would be not allowed. But is the sync functionality I described before also covered by this? Of course there has to be functionality within the app to connect to the WebApp, but the complete sync logic is implemented on the server, not in the iOS app.

The functionality the iOS app offers is "Establish a connection to the WebApp". This functionality works independently from wether the WebApp subscription is active or not. Only the functionality of the WebApp changes depending on the subscription status (accept or deny sync requests).

**So: Is it allowed to add some text like *"There is a WebApp, too. Use this link to got to the WebApp. Follow this link to renew your subscription"* to the WebApp or not?**

Or is the part *"Follow this link to renew your subscription"* forbidden?

What makes the whole thing even more confusing is the following paragraph form the Guidelines:

> **3.1.5 Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App**: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed
>   outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than IAP to
>   collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card
>   entry. Apps may facilitate transmission of approved virtual currencies
>   (e.g. Bitcoin, DogeCoin) provided that they do so in compliance with
>   all state and federal laws for the territories in which the app
>   functions.

Does this read as "Physical Goods and **physical** Services" (e.g. postal delivery in contrast to **digital** Services) or this include all Services?

**So, is the "WebApp Sync Service" covered by this paragraph and thus the usage of external payments not only allowed but necessary?**

Of course I could ask these question directly to Apple. But I would never get an answer. Even if I would, this would still be no guarantee, that the review stuff shares the same interpretation of the rules. So your experience and opinion will be the best "guarantee" I will ever get.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's a very big player so maybe has more leverage, but you can buy a Spotify subscription directly from them on the web or via IAP in their iOS app. Pretty sure 3.1.5 is about things like selling you a refrigerator or getting someone to drive you somewhere.

Comment: The Spotify example would support the argument, that I **have** to offer IAP for the WebApp subscription. Of course the Guidelines do NOT say, that IAP has to be the only option. So offering IAP and web payment would be fine. Question is: Would be web payment only also OK?

Comment: Probably yes, but not inside the app itself. Inside the app I think you could only offer an IAP and could not direct the user to other means of payment.